# TypeError: Firebase is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to follow the firebase Node tutorial:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html

My node.js app is crashing with a "TypeError: Firebase is not a function" error. My index.js file:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://word-word-number.firebaseio.com/");
```

Line two is where the crash happens.

In my package.json I have:

```
"firebase": "^3.0.2",
```

and

```
"node": "5.11.0"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that **the firebase.com tutorial is out-of-date** with how the latest firebase package should be used. Below are the new instructions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

*In your code, you can access Firebase using:*

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.intializeApp({
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
});
```

Alternatively, if you setup a `Service Account` via Permissions in the new Google Firebase dashboard, use the approach referenced in the new official docs here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: Which is why you look at the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_a_database_reference_numbered) first. It contains the updated documentation and a migration guide

Comment: As a newcomer to Firebase, I did not realize that the firebase.com documentation wasn't the official documentation. Hopefully this post will be useful for others in the same position.

Comment: firebase.com is official as it's their site, but on their front page they notify you that they have a newer site, which is located at firebase.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Updated documentation for nodeJs users
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_a_database_reference_numbered
This will probably fix all those errors.