# TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

Following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#full_example) example, I keep getting the error:

```
 TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function
```

From this line in my code:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

(And when I simply try to initialize storage from the [storage guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start), linked from [firebase's npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase), I get the same error.)

In my Node.js project, I'm including the following libraries:

- `const firebase = require('firebase');`
- `var admin = require('firebase-admin');`
- `const fs = require('fs');`

Up to this point, I've successfully been able to read from and write to the firebase database, creating a reference to the database with `var db = admin.database()`, then `var ref = db.ref("/")`... So I know I've configured Firebase and firebase-database correctly. But I'm stuck on `storage`, and have tried both `admin.storage().ref()` and `firebase.storage().ref()`, and `firebase.storage().ref("/")` with the same error message.

I've also tried:

```
var storage = firbase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
```

and

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var storage = app.storage();
```

and with `ref()`'s void argument `()` and with `"/"`... but have the same message, yet to no avail.

I'm using:

- "firebase": "^3.6.4"
- "firebase-admin": "^4.0.4"
- Node.js : v6.9.1

What must I do to successfully create a reference to storage?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369466/typeerror-firebase-is-not-a-function

Comment: @SergChernata No, it's a different error entirely. "`Firebase is not a function`. Their error was they did not initialize Firebase properly, whereas I did, and able to utilize the Firebase database and other features accordingly. Firebase Storage is the issue.

Comment: What do you see when inspecting the `firebase.storage` object? Try to do console.log(JSON.stringify(firebase.storage)). Is it undefined?

Comment: Yes, it's undefined; despite the JSON pointing to the correct URL, which I just double-checked.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**DEPRECATED, see below:**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848966/3873012), instead of firebase storage, in Node.js, `google-cloud` package storage should be used, and it seems that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396389/3873012) should confirm it. Code example:

```
npm i --save google-cloud
```

Then:

```
const gcloud = require('google-cloud')

const storage = gcloud.storage({
    projectId: '<projectID>',
    keyFilename: 'service-account-credentials.json',
});

const bucket = storage.bucket('<projectID>.appspot.com')
```

**As of 2018, this is the correct answer:**

Or using only the storage part of the package:

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/storage
```

And then:

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')
```

Also check [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-cloud#using-the-all-in-one-module-2) for more.

Comment: Already ran into a warning...`npm WARN deprecated gcloud@0.37.0: gcloud has been renamed to google-cloud. To get new features and bug fixes, you must use the new package.`... So I'll post this to keep the info up-to-date... working through this now, thanks to this second answer...

Comment: Corrected the answer to reflect change. Thanks!

Comment: Just found a major unadvertised obstacle... You have to enable billing to use a bucket 

Comment: Your answer got me to the correct track, thanks! For posterity's sake, I'll post an answer detailing my steps.

Comment: Thank you!
I hope here's a way to bypass billing =\

Comment: both `gcloud` and `google-cloud` are depricated. `@google-cloud/storage` is the way to go

Comment: How is this the right answer? It's not deprecated: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

Comment: Google's documentation is wrong, I tried what they said and it doesn't work. The updated answer here does work.

Comment: Correction, the updated answer here does NOT work, it is deprecated too.

Answer (score 122):

I faced the same problem. In my case, I needed to include storage module besides Firebase core.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';  // <----

firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

(npm firebase v5.0.4)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I find that I get 'firebase' has no exported member 'storage' with

firebase.storage().ref()

Answer (score 19):

## Deprecated: please see the accepted answer.

#### Some details to note:

1. Firebase Storage is no longer used with Node.js, so all documentation there is useless for Node.js. Instead, use `google-cloud`. The references and guides for Firebase and Google Cloud do not reflect this as of today.
2. Unlike Firebase, google-cloud costs money, even for small projects.
3. In my case, I'm using the [`firebase-admin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) SDK so I don't have to mess with user authentication at the moment.

---

## Purpose

To create a single Node.js project which uses Firebase and Google Cloud. **Why?** Firebase has a useful database, among other features, and Google Cloud allows cloud file storage and retrieval.

## Directions

### Step 1: Project Creation

Create [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and [Google Cloud (Storage)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) projects.

### Step 2: Install Packages

Using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), install [`firebase-admin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) and [`google-cloud`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) in `Node.js` project.

*Note 1: I used the admin SDK, so after creating the Firebase project, you'll need to go to:*

- Settings(the gear) > *Project Settings* > *Service Accounts* > *Firebase Admin SDK*
- Then you: Select `Node.js` > [Copy/paste the generated code into
  your project] > [click "Generate New Private Key"] > [download the
  generated `json` to preferred location] > [replace
  `"path/to...AccountKey.json"` with the path to the key you just
  generated]

*Note 2: the generated key can be reused in firebase or google-cloud credentials.*

### Step 3: Firebase Setup

Once your project is created, import the [`firebase-admin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) sdk:

The code should look like this, but filled with your info:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("/path/to/generated/json/here.json"),
  databaseURL: "database-url-from-firebase"
});
```

To find the databaseURL, go to 'Storage' in Firebase, and note the URL starting with `gs:` and copy/paste it the the value field of databaseURL.

Next, get a reference to the database you can use:

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/");
console.log('DB ref: ' + ref); //just to debug, if undefined, there's a problem.
```

To learn more about reading/writing to the database, follow [Firebase's own documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

### Step 4: Google-Cloud Billing Setup

After creating a project on Google Cloud, add billing information; buckets cannot be used without billing info.

### Step 5: Google-Cloud Storage Setup

1. Scrolling through the menu (the horizontal 3-bars), click "Storage", then "Enable Billing". Yes, you added billing info, now you need to enable it for that project's buckets.
2. You *should* see that a bucket should already exists from your Firebase project.
3. Click on menu again(3-bar icon), then > *IAM & Admin* > *Settings*
4. At settings, you'll see "Project ID" which should look like "projectName-00000" or "projectName-Some#", **copy that project ID**

### Step 6: Google Cloud in Node.js

In your `index.js`:

```
var gcloud = require('google-cloud');
var gcs = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: 'paste-that-project-id-here',
  keyFilename: 'paste-that-path-to-the-previously-downloaded-json-from-firebase-here'
});
```

Now you can send a file to your storage by:

```
var bucket = gcs.bucket('bucket_name');
var remoteFile = bucket.file('somefile-inThisCaseASong.mp3');
var localFilename = '/Users/you/Music/somefile-inThisCaseASong.mp3';
bucket.upload(localFilename, function(err, file) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('somefile-inThisCaseASong.mp3 is now in your bucket.');
  } else {
    console.log('Error uploading file: ' + err);
  }
});
```

### Step 7: Verify

If the file is visible in Firebase Storage and Google Cloud Storage, you're done!

Comment: how do you authenticate a user and serve him his files during all this?

Comment: If you're downvoting because this isn't a good answer for you... then please refer to the very first line in my answer, which redirects users to the correct answer. I'm keeping this answer here for posterity.

Comment: The updated answer is also out of date, as "npm WARN deprecated google-cloud@0.58.2: The google-cloud package has been deprecated." 
But don't feel bad, it seems google's own document is even MORE out of date.

Answer (score 9):

Year 2020 answer, In my case I include firebase-storage.js in .html file

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Therefore, if you use all Firebase service, you will have

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.5.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>  


<!-- your script calling Firebase Firestore under this line -->
<script> 
....
</script>
```

Comment: See this link for updated and available libs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#expandable-8

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, I had my code as following:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/storage';

firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

So, I found that way is only if you use **Typescript**.

If you use only **ES6**, then you must have:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';

firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

If you use **ES5**, then you must have:

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/storage");

firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

Moreover, you can also use the following way but it is not recommended because you load all services (database,auth,storage,etc):

```
import firebase from "firebase";

firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

Tested with Firebase 7.15.2

Answer (score 7):

When using Storage with Firebase, you're correct that you can't add buckets on the free tier.  However, you DO get a bucket (just one) by default.  My (eventually) successful approach was to:

1. Add Storage to my project in Firebase (NOT Google Cloud)
2. Add the Admin SDK and set up the necessary Service Account as per the Google Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=1
3. Add the `@google-cloud/storage` package as per the instructions on using the Admin SDK with storage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start?authuser=1
4. Initialize the app:

   ```
   admin.initializeApp({
     credential: admin.credential.cert("/path/to/generated/json/here.json"),
     storageBucket: "folder-URL-from-Storage-page-excluding-gs://"
   });
   ```
5. Access the bucket object with (from Admin SDK docs):

   `const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();`
6. Operate on the bucket with the storage library.  Example:

   ```
   bucket.upload('/path/file.ext', function(err, file, apiResponse) {
     //Do Stuff
   });
   ```

NOTE: I spent a couple of hours convinced it wasn't working because I didn't have a bucket, but it turned out my mistake was including the `gs://` in the path to my storage bucket when initializing.

Comment: I am getting error "TypeError: admin.storage is not a function"

Comment: Tushar create an app w/o the security cert. Morgan, thanks. This is the correct answer. I'd add that `.save()` works for Buffers if you don't have the file locally (e.g. user needs to upload avatar or something).

Comment: For anyone looking at getting the public url:
`bucket.file('image.jpg').getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-09-2491'
}).then(results => {
  let url = results[0];
});
`



You can also find details here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js

Comment: I am have a problem, this is working fine `let bucket = admin.storage().bucket()`
but I have a folder in storage `users/` and inside this folder I am storing images. How can I access this folder ??

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED FOR VERSION 9**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// Set the configuration for your app
// TODO: Replace with your app's config object
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket-url>'
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have added  a script tag with this src in you HTML file  **< src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.12.0/firebase-storage.js"** to your project

- Here **7.12.0** will be replaced with your current working version.

Answer (score 2):

I think V9 of firebase has a different way of letting us use its storage. For using firebase storage you can import storage as -

```
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
```

Now you can follow this -

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it change if you try to do it like the following?

```
// Initialize the default app:
const app = firebase.initializeApp(appConfig)

// Initialize storage from the *app* object:
const storage = app.storage()
```

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), it seems that this is an alternate method. I prefer this one, as this links the storage to the app, making the code more readable, and more functional

Comment: No change... unless a new error counts... On the line, `var storage = app.storage();` I get this error:  `TypeError: app.storage is not a function`... And I did do this: `var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);` before hand.

Comment: I understand this didn't work, and I'll add a second answer with a better try. That said, I'll leave this one here for potential web-coding googlers who may find themselves here. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use firebase.storage(), but it took some time to figure it out. It only works when importing like this:

```
//Importing
const firebase = require('firebase')
require('firebase/storage')

//Calling the function (You can call it normally then)
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

I'm serious, whenever trying to import as firebase.storage() or doing anything different it wouldn't work! Hope it helps some of you guys.

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me and didn't add a huge amount of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

in app.module initilize
`import firebase from 'firebase/app'`;
`import 'firebase/storage'`;

`firebase.storage();`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have fixed it in a new version of the library.
Just run `npm update` on the relevant package(s) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem when I test my app locally, but everything **works when the project is deployed**.

This way, I actually use the following workaround :

```
if (!firebase.storage) {
    // prevent crash when working locally
    return;
}
let ref = firebase.storage().ref()
// perform production stuff ...
```

It's a little bit curious, but it works in my case.

Comment: That is very interesting! In my case, my app was also deployed, so what’s interesting is this works for you but not me. My work around was using Google Cloud storage

Answer (score 0):

The firebase storage service still works (and AFAIK is not deprecated) in browsers.  The firebase storage service is not available on server environments including during server-side-rendering.

This is how I've done it:

```js
// only import uploadHandler client-side.
const uploadHandler = typeof window === 'object' ? require('./handlers').imageHandler : () => false; // ssr only
```

Then in `handlers.js` you can safely use the firebase storage service normally.

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const bucketObjectRef = storageRef.child('myFile.jpg');
```

As of 4/3/2020, it seems the entire firebase suite of products is still supported in browser environments.

[image: firebase environment support table]

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#namespace

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when I was integrating firebase's storage on the browser (webapp)

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Just add that line, and the bug is gone!

Answer (score -1):

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

Then firebase.storage().ref() should work.

Hope this helps.