# How to delete FireStorage file using Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to delete some images triggered by FireStore's update.
If a user delete images she registered, Firestore will update her post's URL's array.

Post URL in the array is like this.

```
http://192.168.1.5:9199/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/post_images%2F1CA97725-5CF8-4C1B-AD70-674B19A2EE75
```

I developed the cloud functions to delete images comparing to the previous states using Admin SDK's TypeScript .

```
export const deletePostImages = functions
  .firestore.document("/posts/{postId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const oldData = change.before.data()
    const newData = change.after.data()

    
    const deletedImages = oldData.imageUrls.filter(
      (oldImage: string) => !newData.imageUrls.includes(oldImage)
    )

    const promises = deletedImages.map((url: string) => {
 
      const fileRef = admin.storage().bucket().file(url)
      return fileRef.delete()
    })
    await Promise.all(promises)
  })
```

But it seems the combination by my file path and `bucket()` is wrong.

The Error URL `fileRef` I got is here.

```
http://192.168.1.5:9199/b/example.appspot.com/o/192.168.1.5:9199/b/example.appspot.com/o/post_images%2F1CA97725-5CF8-4C1B-AD70-674B19A2EE75
```

I already read some docs like [How to delete a file using Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635498/how-to-delete-a-file-using-cloud-functions)

But I don't know how I should use `bucket()` and url in my context.
How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should only give the file location on your `file()` method instead of giving the full URL in it as the `bucket()` needs your bucket name and `file()` needs the object location in your bucket. e.g.:

```
const projectId = "your-project-id"
const objectPath = "your-object-path" // "post_images/2F1CA97725-5CF8-4C1B-AD70-674B19A2EE75"
const fileRef = admin.storage().bucket(`${projectId}.appspot.com`).file(`${objectPath}`)
return fileRef.delete()
```