# firebase.storage() is not a function in jest test cases

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, jestjs

I am using Jest to test my firebase functions. This is all in the browser, so I don't have any conflicts with firebase on the server side. When I use `firebase.auth()` or `firebase.database()` everything works fine. When I try to use `firebase.storage()` my tests fail.

Here is my firebase import and initialization:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import config from '../config';

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
export const firebaseAuth = firebaseApp.auth();
export const firebaseDb = firebaseApp.database();
```

I have an imageUtils file that has an upload function in it:

```
import { firebaseApp } from './firebase';

export const uploadImage = (firebaseStoragePath, imageURL) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // reject if there is no imagePath provided
    if (!firebaseStoragePath) reject('No image path was provided. Cannot upload the file.');

    // reject if there is no imageURL provided
    if (!imageURL) reject('No image url was provided. Cannot upload the file');

    // create the reference
    const imageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref().child(firebaseStoragePath);

    let uploadTask;
    // check if this is a dataURL
    if (isDataURL(imageURL)) {
      // the image is a base64 image string
      // create the upload task
      uploadTask = imageRef.putString(imageURL);
    } else {
      // the image is a file
      // create the upload task
      uploadTask = imageRef.put(imageURL);
    }

    // monitor the upload process for state changes
    const unsub = uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot) => {
        // this is where we can check on progress
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error.serverResponse);
        unsub();
      }, () => {
        // success function
        resolve(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
        unsub();
      });
  });
};
```

And I am trying to create a test case for that function and every time it fails with:

```
TypeError: _firebase3.firebaseApp.storage is not a function
```

When I run the app normally everything works fine and I never get errors about storage() being undefined or not a function. It is only when I try to run a test case.

I have set a `console.dir(firebaseApp);` line in the firebase import, and it comes back with both `auth()` and `database()` but no storage. How can I get storage to import/initialize/exist properly?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352150/typeerror-firebase-storage-is-not-a-function

Comment: I don't think so. That is referring to firebase on nodejs, and I am strictly using it in the browser. According to the firebase docs, calling storage from the browser is still a supported use case.

Answer (score 15):

Add the following import

```
import "firebase/storage";
```

Comment: import ```firebase/storage``` in my tests? or import and use in the initialization of my storageRef?

Comment: Import it into your initialization or declaration of storageRef, I found this also fixed my test. However, Firebase provides a warning relating to dates

Comment: Wow Thanks! You save a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was fixed in a [recent update to the firebase javascript package](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js):
[image: update to firebase javascript package]

Comment: It just happened for me in 5.0.4.  hsc's answer still fixed it though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Another possible solution:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage";
```