# Jest Test - The current environment does not support the specified persistence type

Tags: firebase, jestjs, firebaseui

I use jest to run some test on my Create React App with Firebase Web SDK coupled with FirebaseUI

Whenever I try to run some tests with --env=jsdom - I run into :
`The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.` seems related to Auth

Are there any known related issue/workaround ? the code seems to work/compile  properly aside from the tests.

Google didn't help much

Here is the test, pretty basic.
HAd to add `import "firebase/storage";` because of this : [firebase.storage() is not a function in jest test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091672/firebase-storage-is-not-a-function-in-jest-test-cases)

Thanks in advance

```
import React from "react";

import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import "firebase/storage";
import {filterIngredientsToRemove} from "./shoppingList-reducer";

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe("", () => {
    let shoppingList;
    let recipeId;

    beforeEach(() => {
        shoppingList = {
            shoppingListItems: {
                "1234": {ingredientId: 987, name: "patate", recipeId: 1234},
                "2345": {ingredientId: 987, name: "patate", recipeId: 5432}
            },
            shoppingListRecipes: {
                "1234": {portion: 3}
            }
        };

        recipeId = 1234;
    });

    it("should filter out the shoppinglistItems with the provided recipeId", () => {
        const result = filterIngredientsToRemove(recipeId, shoppingList.shoppingListItems);
        expect(result).toEqual([{ingredientId: 987, name: "patate", recipeId: 1234}]);
    });
});
```

Comment: any update on this issue? I'm also running into the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Are you setting persistence in your firebase config? Persistence is not supported in the test environment, so you can do something like this to circumvent it:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' 
  ? firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE 
  : firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too. The problem seems to come from the firebaseui constructor, specifically this line of code in my app:

```
new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.firebase.auth())
```

What I did to solve it was initialize the ui object only when actually using it to sign on, not just as a static (typescript) variable. This let me run jest tests that didn't try to sign on just fine.

```
private static ui: firebaseui.auth.AuthUI | undefined

static startAuthOnElement (selectorToUse: string, onSignedIn: () => void) {
    if (this.ui === undefined) this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.firebase.auth())
// more code
}
```

This way all the code that doesn't call startAuthOnElement never runs the firebaseui constructor. This lets me run my jest tests just fine and auth still works in the app.