# How update an image from Expressjs to Google Cloud Storage / Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, express, firebase

I'm learning about ExpressJS and i'm trying to upload an image to Firebase storage by Node.

I have received the error:`firebase.storage().ref() is not a function`, and searching about it I found these [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352150/typeerror-firebase-storage-is-not-a-function) and discovered the firebase storage doesn't supported by Node.

Now that is the Question: I have a File Object received by html input file but I simply don't know how to upload that to Google Cloud Storage. How I can do it ?

The solutions I have found all use the filepath name to upload, but I like to upload the File Object (file).

My code:

```
req.pipe(req.busboy);
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
    console.log("Uploading: " + filename);

    // Trying GCS
    var remoteReadStream = bucket.file('giraffe.jpg').createReadStream();
    console.log(remoteReadStream);
    //var localWriteStream = 
    fs.createWriteStream('/photos/zoo/giraffe.jpg');
//remoteReadStream.pipe(localWriteStream);

// Trying Firebase
//storageRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
//  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
//});
});
```

Thanks until now.

Comment: You can find options here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

Comment: You can use the Google Cloud Storage node SDK.  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-storage-ga

Answer (score 0):

I have saw these documents before to post this topic. I decide to test upload a basic image by file path name like:
`home/pedro/Downloads/outros icones/1532.png`
Using this [code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#upload) and i received the error: could not autenticate the error, but I downloaded the `keyfile.json` of OAuth2.0 and configurated it.

```
var x = '/home/pedro/Downloads/outros icones/1532.png'
var localReadStream = fs.createReadStream(x);
var remoteWriteStream = bucket.file('zebra.jpg').createWriteStream();
localReadStream.pipe(remoteWriteStream);
```

The variable `bucket` is the bucket reference configurated (the begin of all of these documentations) and the `fs` is the require of fs.

I'm very confused now...