# VueJS this.$firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I've added this code to my main.js file.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
const config = {
  apiKey: '###########',,

  authDomain: '###########',,

  databaseURL: '###########',,

  projectId: '###########',,

  storageBucket: '###########',,

  messagingSenderId: '###########',
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase;
```

And then inside my `imageUpload` method

```
const storageRef = this.$firebase.storage().ref();
```

This gives me an error

> this.$firebase.storage is not a function

Why could this happen?

Any idea?

Comment: Not used Firebase myself but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352150/typeerror-firebase-storage-is-not-a-function suggests that you need to `import 'firebase/storage'`.

Comment: @skirtle this worked for me. Please add this as an answer. So I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks a lot. =)