# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to create a reference to my firebase storage but I am getting the error: ***Uncaught TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function***.
How can I solve this?

There is a similar question where node is used, but in my case I am not using node and hence I don't know if the answer will solve my problem.[TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352150/typeerror-firebase-storage-is-not-a-function)

My code is shown below:

**In my app.js:**

```
console.log("Initialisation Successful!");
var db = firebase.firestore();
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var imagesRef = storageRef.child('Images');


function addExerise(){
    var exerciseName = document.getElementById("ename").value;
    var exercisePart = document.getElementById("body_part").value;
    var exerciseLevel = document.getElementById("elevel").value;
    var file = document.getElementById("eimage");
    console.log(file);

    file.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
      let imageFile = evt.target.files[0] // upload the first file only
      let uploadTask = imagesRef.put(imageFile)
  })



    /*var file = storageRef.child(file.name);
    ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
         alert("File Uploaded")
         console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });*/


    db.collection("Exercises").add({
        Name: exerciseName,
        bodyPart: exercisePart,
        Level: exerciseLevel,
        //image: file

    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Data entered successfully!");
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.error("Error!", error);
    });
}
```

**Firebase Initialisation in my html page:**

```
<!--Firebase-->
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

            <script>
                var firebaseConfig = {
                    apiKey: "############################",
                    authDomain: "########.firebaseapp.com",
                    databaseURL: "###########.firebaseio.com",
                    projectId: "#############",
                    storageBucket: "gs://##########.appspot.com",
                    messagingSenderId: "##############",
                    appId: "###############################"
                  };
                // Initialize Firebase
                firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            </script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        <!--/Firebase-->
```

Solved:

Added the line below in my html.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Comment: add [`https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-storage.js`](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/85fosr4a/)

Comment: Yes, it solved it. Thank You.

Comment: In the future, please do a web search for the error message before posting to Stack Overflow.  This is a very common problem and I suspect you would have found the solution very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Firebase console, have you added the Storage service and regenerated the initialization code to put into your HTML? I see that you have the `firebase-app.js` and `firebase-firestore.js` scripts added, but it looks like you don't have one for storage. Perhaps adding that service and added the relevant script to your HTML will fix the problem.

**Edit:**
Adding `firebase-storage.js` will fix the issue:

```js
console.log(firebase.storage);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, yes I have added storage service but it does not appear in my initialization code.

Comment: @RoopanJaulin Sorry, my mistake. If you go into your Firebase console, go to your project, then click `Storage` on the left side. You should be able to set up the storage service for your project, and it will give you instructions on how to enable the service, including how to create the `firebase.storage()` function.

Comment: Yes, the firebase-storage.gs solved the problem, as per yours and shrys answer.  
                                                                                                                   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>                                                                                                     
Thanks a lot.