# firebase storage: storage.ref is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I would like to use storage service from Firebase with a nodeJS api (hosted on "firebase functions") to allow the users to upload his avatars.

So I read the doc from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

and I do:

admin.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const config = require('./config.js');

admin.initializeApp(config);

const db = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage();

module.exports = { admin, db, storage };
```

user.js

```
const { admin, db, storage } = require('../util/admin');

exports.postAvatar = async (request, response) => {

  const storageRef = storage.ref();

}
```

but I have the following error: `storage.ref is not a function`

Is something is missing from the documentation ?

The console.log of storage const is:

```
Storage {
  INTERNAL: StorageInternals {},
  storageClient: Storage {...},
  appInternal: FirebaseApp {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[admin.storage()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.App#storage) returns a [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage) object.  If you want to use it to refer to a file in your default storage bucket, you should use its `bucket()` method with no parameters, and it will give you a [Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/Bucket) object from the Google Cloud nodejs SDK.

There are no methods called `ref()` anywhere in that SDK.  It's not much like the JavaScript web client SDK.  You will have to learn a different but similar API to work with content in using the [Cloud Storage node SDK](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/).  The Admin SDK just essentially wraps this API.

```
const file = storage.bucket().file('/path/to/file');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```js
const storage = storage.bucket() // you can also put your bucket-id from config
const storageRef = storage.ref()
```

Also check this answer. [TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352150/typeerror-firebase-storage-is-not-a-function)