# Retrieve firebase data to web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```js
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBz13eirmEOGD1uXOZwf6tKGnEsjfwsUFo",
    authDomain: "platformtechproject.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://platformtechproject.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "platformtechproject",
    storageBucket: "platformtechproject.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1065758005439"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  
  var database = firebase.database();

 var msgRef = firebase.database().ref('survey');
    
  
  //console.log(firebase);
  
var msgRef = firebase().ref('survey');
msgRef.on('value',gotData,errData);
```

I continue getting this error [Uncaught TypeError: firebase is not a function] as i am trying to read firebase data to web.
[Chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNnC6.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369466/typeerror-firebase-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how your code must be:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBz13eirmEOGD1uXOZwf6tKGnEsjfwsUFo",
    authDomain: "platformtechproject.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://platformtechproject.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "platformtechproject",
    storageBucket: "platformtechproject.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1065758005439"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


  var database = firebase.database();

 var msgRef = database.ref('survey');


msgRef.on("child_added",function(snapshot) {
  var changedPost = snapshot.val();
  console.log(changedPost)
});
</script>
```

The code above works as you expect:
[image]

Note that msgRef listens on these predefined "events".

Details here: [Read Event Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 var database = firebase.database();

var msgRef = firebase.database().ref('survey');


 //console.log(firebase);

var msgRef = firebase().ref('survey');
msgRef.on('value',gotData,errData);
```

to this:

```
 var database = firebase.database();
 var msgRef = database.ref('survey');
 msgRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  //retrieve data
 });
```